# Deriving the Hessian from the limit definition of the derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Could someone possibly help me understand how I can derive the Hessian matrix of a twice-differentiable function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ using the limit definition of the second derivative. Namely, how does: $\lim_{h -> 0}\frac{\nabla f(x+h) - \nabla f(x)}{h}$ result in the Hessian $\nabla^2 f(x)$. If I happen to be wrong about this, could you please point out what I am misunderstanding?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Let's start here: do you understand how $\nabla f$ is found from $f$ using the limit definition of the first derivative?

Comment: derivative doesn't work that way in $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: @user251257 It can be understood that way, so long as the $h$ is understood to be vector-valued.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: ... how is the division between vectors defined? I doubt $x_i / y_j$ will really work

Comment: We take $\|h\|$ on the bottom.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom then you only have a vector as second derivative

Comment: You could define the derivative of a vector-*valued* function individually by component.  Granted, the definition
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x) - f'(x)h}{\|h\|} = 0
$$
will work in all cases without modification.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, so far, I understand that for each component of $x$, $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i} = \lim_{h->0} \frac{f(x + e_i h) - f(x)}{h}$ where $e_i$ is the standard basis vector.

Comment: @user251257 again, the sacrifice here is that this only works for scalar-valued functions.  Vector-valued and matrix-valued functions are taken individually by component.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom what do you mean? your limit definition is correct. However, I meant that OP has a totally different limit "definition" which won't work.

Answer (score 4):

To extend [user251257](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/251257/user251257)'s answer, we have that, for any vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\nabla f (x + hv) - \nabla  f(x)}{h} = \nabla^2 f(x)v$$ We can deduce this directly from his/her answer and subsequent comments since, as he/she suggested, $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\nabla f (x + he_i) - \nabla f(x)}{h} =  \nabla^2 f(x)e_i = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\end{bmatrix}_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

For more on this topic, I recommend reading about directional derivatives in a multivariate analysis text such as that of [Loomis & Sternberg](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf).

Comment: I would recommend that you include part of user251257's answer right here, give the user credit and make this a complete answer so that someone reading it can understand it as a whole.

Comment: You missed a $\nabla$ in your derivations: it should be $\nabla f(x+hv) - \nabla f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks @PantelisSopasakis. Made the edit

Answer (score 3):

In the end of the day, $\nabla f$ is a function on several variables that produces a vector (or dual vector, depending on your point of view). What we need, then, is a definition of the derivative that applies to *vector-valued* (or matrix-valued) functions.

One definition that works is as follows: suppose we have the function
$$
F(x) = \pmatrix{F_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) & \cdots & F_m(x_1,\dots,x_n)}
$$
Then we can define
$$
\nabla F(x) = 
\pmatrix{
-\nabla F_1-\\
-\nabla F_2-\\
\vdots\\
-\nabla F_m-\\
}
$$
so that each row is the gradient of a function.  Now, if $F(x) = \nabla f$, then we end up with the Hessian $\nabla^2f$.

On the other hand, another way to extend the definition is to say that the derivative of a function $F(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ at a point $(z_1,\dots,z_n)$ is the unique linear function $[F'(z_1,\dots,z_n)](x_1,\dots,x_n)$ which we can write as $A(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ satisfying
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(x + h) - F(x) - A(h)}{\|h\|} = 0
$$
This is (in a sense) the most general definition of a derivative, and it is indeed equivalent to the definition given above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! One question: what are the dimensions of $x$ when you say: $F(x)$ ?

Comment: $x$ is a vector with $n$ components.

Answer (score 1):

The quotient 
$\frac{\nabla f(x + h) - \nabla f(x)}{h}$ isn't properly defined if $n > 1$.

However,
the limit
$$ \lim_{h\to 0 }\frac{\nabla f(x + he_i) - \nabla f(x)}{h} $$
gives the $i$ th column (or row depending on your preference how to write $\nabla f$) of $\nabla^2 f(x)$, for $1\le i \le n$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you be more specific as to why this is a column and not a scalar?

Comment: @Pedrito: The gradient is the vector consists of the partial derivatives of $f$, one for each argument. If $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, then you have $n$ arguments, so $\nabla f(x) \in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @user25127: I understand that. I guess what I'm not getting is why this is exactly the i-th column of the Hessian. Also, how would you set up the limit expression to get the entire Hessian matrix?

Comment: the $i$-th column, because in the limit I only vary the $i$-th argument (see x+he_i)$. Division between vectors isn't defined. You can't write the complete Hessian as limit. This or the limit in the answer of @Omnomnomnom is the best you get.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function.

Then, at a point $p$, the derivative $Df\big|_p: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ can be computed by (but is not defined by)

$$
Df\big|_p(v) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(p+hv)-f(p)}{h}
$$

If $f$ is differentiable then $Df\big|_p$ is a linear function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.  We have that $f(p+v) \approx f(p)+Df\big|_p(v)$

If $f$ is twice differentiable, then we can think of its second derivative as a bilinear form $Hf\big|_p:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.  It can be computed by (but not defined by)

$$
Hf\big|_p(v,w) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{Df_{p+hv}(w) - Df\big|_p(w)}{h}
$$

We have that $Df\big|_{p+v}(w) \approx Df\big|_p(w)+Hf\big|_p(v,w)$.

It also turns out (the beginning of the multivariable Taylor's theorem), that $f(p+v) \approx f(p)+Df\big|_p(v)+\frac{1}{2!}Hf\big|_p(v,v)$.

The pattern continues with higher derivatives being higher order symmetric tensors.