# Deriving hessian as best linear approximation

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, vector-analysis, hessian-matrix

I'm having trouble understanding how to derive the Hessian based on the following definition of the derivative of a multivariable function (the derivation is from "An introduction to optimization 4th edition by Edwin Chong and Stanislaw Zak).

> Any linear transformation from $R^n$ to $R^m$, and in particular the derivative $\mathcal{L}$ of $f: R^n \rightarrow R^m$ can be represented by an m x n matrix. To find the matrix representation $L$ of the derivative $\mathcal{L}$ of a differentiate function $f: R^n \rightarrow R^m$ we use the natural basis $\{e_i,..., e_n\}$ for $R^n$. Consider the vectors. $$ x_j = x_0 + te_j, \quad j = 1, ...., n $$ By the definition of the derivative we have
> $$ \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_j) - (tLe_j + f(x_0))}{t} = 0 $$
> for j = 1,...,n. This means that
> $$ \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_j) - f(x_0)}{t} = Le_j $$
> But $Le_j$ is the jth column of the matrix $L$. On the other hand, the vector $x_j$ differs from $x_0$ only in the jth coordinate, and in that coordinate the difference is just the number t. Therefore, the left side of the preceding equation is the partial derivative
> $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x_0)$$
> Because vector limits are computed by taking the limit of each coordinate function, it follows that if
> $$ 
> f(x) = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
>  f_1(x) \\
>  \vdots \\
>  f_n(x) \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> then
> $$ 
> \frac{df}{dx_j}(x_0) = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
>  \frac{df_1}{dx_j}(x_0) \\
>  \vdots \\
>  \frac{df_n}{dx_j}(x_0) \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> And the matrix $L$ has the form
> $$
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{df_1}{dx_1}(x_0) \cdots \frac{df_1}{dx_n}(x_0) \\
> \vdots \\
> \frac{df_m}{dx_1}(x_0) \cdots \frac{df_m}{dx_n}(x_0) \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

All of that makes sense, and I understand that if we assume that $f: R^n \rightarrow R$ then we get the row vector
$$ L = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{df}{dx_1}(x_0), \cdots, \frac{df}{dx_n}(x_0)
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

which is the best linear approximation for $f$ around $x_0$ in the sense that

$$ f(x) \approx  f(x_0) + L(x_0)(x - x_0)$$

which is the first two terms of the Taylor series centered at $x_0$.

However, the book then goes on the define the gradient as $\nabla f = Df(x)^T$ and then defines the Hessian as the derivate of the gradient

$$ D^2f = D(\nabla f) $$

It's this "defining the Hessian as the derivative of the gradient" that I don't understand.
Given the definition of the derivative they presented earlier as the best linear map (lets call this new map K), I would assume that $$ D^2f = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{Df(x_0 + te_j) - Df(x_0)}{t} = Ke_j$$

But the left-hand side of this equation is a row vector, and the right-hand side is a column vector, which doesn't really make any sense. So my question is how do I use the definition of "best linear approximation" from above to differentiate $Df(x)$ and arrive at the Hessian?

I think I might also have a misunderstanding about which part of $Df(x)$ is the "function". I usually think of functions as mapping from some input space to some output space, and derivates are also just functions from the same input space to the same output space, ie.

$$ f(x) = x^2$$
$$ f'(x) = 2x $$

Where the derivate itself is a function that maps inputs to outputs. But if I assume that $Df(x) = $$ L = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{df}{dx_1}(x_0), \cdots, \frac{df}{dx_n}(x_0)
\end{bmatrix} 
$ then this isn't a function as I normally understand it, since $f: R^n \rightarrow R$ but $L$ takes in some vector $x \in R^n $ and spits out a vector $L_0 \in R^n$. So if I'm wrong in understanding what the derivate of a multivariable function is I would also appreciate clearing that up.

As for research I've done:

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431326/deriving-the-hessian-from-the-limit-definition-of-the-derivative) derives the Hessian using the limit definition of the gradient, but as stated above I'm not sure why we need to switch to the gradient to define the Hessian in the first place.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809169/hessian-matrix-as-derivative-of-gradient) seems to insert a transpose into the derivative to make the numbers match the Hessian, which I don't understand the reasoning for.

I've also done some reading on Frechet derivatives, which seems similar to/is the same as the "best linear map" definition presented above, but I wasn't able to find anything that answered my question with that line of research either.

Comment: The Hessian is simply a matrix of the second partials. Given a function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, one can identify its gradient as a map $g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$. Now, the derivative of $g$ is a matrix whose $ij$th entry is given by $\partial_j g_i$, that is, the $j$th partial of the $i$th component of $g$. This results in a matrix whose $ij$th entry is $\partial_i\partial_j f$.

Comment: Note that we are interpreting the values vector fields take on as column vectors. Now, the derivative itself is actually a function $Df: \mathbb R^n \to \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n)$. However, if one takes the transpose, that is, looks at the gradient, then it is simply $\nabla f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, and to differentiate $\nabla f$, you just apply the rules you are already familiar with.

Comment: The Hessian is typically denoted $\nabla^2 f$, and can be thought of much like the second derivative for uni-variate scalar fields. It is the best quadratic approximation in the sense $$f(x+h) = f(x)+\nabla f(x)^Th+\frac{1}{2}h^T\nabla^2 f(x)h+o(\lvert h\rvert^2)$$

Comment: I just noticed I didn't really address this sentence in my answer: "...derivates are also just functions from the same input space to the same output space..." I think this might be your main issue. *This is not what the differential does*. Suppose we have $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Then $f'$ **is not** the differential of $f$. Actually, $$ Df_x(h) = f'(x)h$$ where $h \in \mathbb R$...

Comment: ...So this is the distinction I make: a *differential* captures how a function changes in any given direction. A *derivative* is something that multiplies with a direction to give the differential. Consider also that if $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ then $$ Df_x(h) = h\cdot(\nabla f(x)) $$ where $h \in \mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\Hom{\mathrm{Hom}}
$I think you are getting confused by the use of matrices/coordinates here,
which are completely unecessary.
So let us do away with them.
There's is also no reason to restrict our discussion to $\R^n$
since virtually nothing changes if just use a general vector space,
and in fact we will need this

So let $V, W$ be finite-dimensional (real) *normed* vector spaces
with norms $||\cdot||_V$ and $||\cdot||_W$.
The choice of norms is actually irrelevant
since all norms on a given finite dimensional vector space
generate the same topology, meaning in particular that the notion of
convergence is independent of the norm chosen.
Now let $f : V \to W$ and choose $x \in V$.
The *differential of $f$ at $x$*
(specifically called the *Fréchet derivative*,
but I would personally not prefer the term "derivative" here)
is the *unique* linear transformation $Df_x : V \to W$
which "best approximates $f$"; specifcally
$$
  \lim_{||h||_V \to 0}\frac{||f(x+h) - f(x) - Df_x(h)||_W}{||h||_V} = 0,
$$
or in other words $[f(x+h)-f(x)]/||h||_V$ converges to $Df_x(h)/||h||_V$
under the norm $||\cdot||_W$ as $||h||_V \to 0$.
For $\epsilon \in \R$ and fixed $h$ it follows that
$$
  Df_x(h) = \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{f(x+\epsilon h)-f(x)}\epsilon.
$$
Another way to state this is that if $||h||_V$ is "small enough" then
$$
  f(x + h) \approx f(x) + Df_x(h).
$$
In this sense $Df_x(h)$ is the "change of $f$ in the direction $h$".

If we were to chooses bases for $V, W$,
then we could represent out vectors as column vectors and $Df_x$ as a matrix.
If $V = \R^m$ and $W = \R^n$ and we choose the standard bases,
the matrix of $Df_x$ is the Jacobian matrix.

The space $\Hom(V, W)$ of linear transformations
is itself a finite dimensional vector space,
so we can also differentiate with it.
In particular $x \mapsto Df_x$ is a function $V \to \Hom(V, W)$;
Thus the *second differential $D^2f_x$ of $f$ at $x$*
is a *multilinear function* $V\times V \to W$ defined by
$$
  D^2f_x(h, k) = D[y \mapsto Df_y]_x(h)(k).
$$
Note that $D[y \mapsto Df_y]_x : V \to \Hom(V, W)$,
so first we evaluate on $h$ to get $D[y \mapsto Df_y]_x(h) : V \to W$,
and then on $k$ to finally get $D^2f_x(h, k) \in W$.
This is the best *second-order, bilinear* approximation to $f$,
in the sense that if $h, k \in V$ with $||h||_V, ||k||_V$ "small"
then simply using the definition of the differential gives
$$
  f(x + k + h)
    \approx f(x + k) + Df_{x+k}(h)
    \approx f(x) + Df_x(k) + Df_x(h) + D^2f_x(h,k).
$$
We can also unravel the definition of $D^2f_x$ to get a limit expression
for $D^2f_x(h,k)$ with fixed $h, k$:
$$\begin{aligned}
  D^2f_x(h,k)
    &= \lim_{\eta\to0}\frac{Df_{x+\eta k}(h) - Df_x(h)}\eta
\\
    &= \lim_{\eta\to0}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}
      \frac{f(x+\eta k+\epsilon h) - f(x+\eta k) - f(x+\epsilon h) + f(x)}
           {\epsilon\eta}.
\end{aligned}$$
In the particular case that $k = h$, we take $\eta = \epsilon$ to get
$$
  D^2f_x(h,h)
    = \lim_{\epsilon\to0}
      \frac{f(x+2\epsilon h) - 2f(x+\epsilon h) + f(x)}
           {\epsilon^2}.
$$

It is uninteresting to differentiate $y \mapsto Df_x(y)$
because the differential of any linear function is itself;
that is, if $f$ is linear then
$$
  Df_x(h) = f(h),
$$
so in particular
$$
  D[y \mapsto Df_x(y)]_z(k) = Df_x(k).
$$

Another name for *multilinear function* is *tensor*.
When $V = W$,
$D^2f_x$ is a type $(1,2)$-tensor (it takes in two vectors and spits out one);
when $W = \R$, it is a type $(0,2)$-tensor;
and generally when $W = V^{\otimes k}$ it is a type $(k,2)$-tensor.

Linear functions $V \to V$ are type $(1,1)$-tensors,
so typically this is how matrices are thought of as well.
However, given a $(0,2)$-tensor $T$,
we can form a matrix $\mathbf T$ whose entries are $T(e_i, e_j)$
where $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^m$ is a basis for $V$;
given vector $v_1, v_2 \in V$ expressed as column vectors in this basis,
$$
  T(v_1, v_2) = v_1^{\top}\mathbf Tv_2.
$$

Now take $V = \R^m$ and $W = \R$ so that $f : \R^m \to \R$.
Then $D^2f_x : \R^m\times\R^m \to \R$;
the matrix corresponding to this $(0,2)$-tensor
expressed in the standard basis of $\R^m$ is the Hessian.

---

The moral of the above story is this: the differential of some $f$ gives us a function $x \mapsto Df_x$, so we can also differentiate this to get $D^2f_x$. Both applications of $D$ also need a direction to differentiate along, so $D^2f_x$ has two arguments giving us $D^2f_x(h, k)$. If $f$ is a function taking vectors to scalars, then it turns out that there is a matrix $\mathbf H_x$ (dependent on $x$) such that
$$
  D^2f_x(h, k) = h^\top\mathbf H_x k,
$$
and we call $\mathbf H$ the Hessian of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! To be honest, I'm an engineer, not a math major, so I don't really understand anything after the $Hom(V, W)$ part (I only "know" what $Hom(V, W)$ means since I looked it up after you posted. I've taken linear algebra so I'm familiar with linear functions, but multilinear is once again something that I've only seen when trying to answer this question. Do you have any resource recommendations for learning the foundations to understand your answer? I'll just take the Hessian as a fact and spend time understanding its derivation later, once I'm done with the class.

Comment: @NickRighi I added a sort of summary at the end of my answer, I hope that that helps somewhat. I will also add here: A *multi*linear function is just a function of multiple arguments which is linear in each argument. So saying "$F : V\times V \to W$ is multilinear" is shorthand for: the function $v \mapsto F(v, u)$ is linear for each fixed $u \in V$, and similarly the function $v \mapsto F(u, v)$ is linear. Since this particular $F$ has two arguments, it is also called *bilinear*...

Comment: You are very likely very familiar with some bilinear functions: multiplication in an algebra (e.g. real numbers, complex numbers, quaternions) is bilinear, as are the dot and cross products of vectors. Sadly, I do not have a reference to give that I think will help; if someone else has suggestions they are very welcome.

Comment: That does make more sense, thanks!